# How to determine if a regression is feasible?

Tags: regression, linear-model

I am trying to build a regression model following the instructions from the book [Introduction to linear regression analysis](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470542810.html) by D. Montgomery and others.

I am about to perform *"all possible regressions"*, but first I have to determine if they are feasible. But I can not find anything in the book (or via google) on how to do this?

tldr: How do you determine if a regression is feasible?

Comment: What do you mean by *feasible*?

Comment: I'm not really sure what it means in this context. Basically I have fitted a full regression model with 12 regressors and then:
1. Residual analysis
2. Determined the need for data transformation
3. A multicollinearity check

And now I'm supposed to perform all possible regressions, IF the are feasible.

Comment: Perhaps *feasible* means that your computer can do it relatively quickly and you do not have to wait a few thousand years before it is done? $2^{12}=4096$ is not a very large number, so it is feasible in this sense.

Comment: That was also a thought of mine, but I am not totally convinced by it. Maybe if you look at the suggested approach if some regression is NOT feasible, it will become more clear what is meant by it? "If all possible regressions are not feasible, use stepwise selection techniques
to generate the largest model such that all possible regressions are feasible." (C. Montgomery, 2012)

Comment: I think it has something to with which combinations of regressors that are allowed to still produce a valid model for the reponse variable..?

Comment: I don't know. I think more context is needed.

Comment: The textbook is not "C. Montgomery": it's by Douglas Montgomery, Elizabeth Peck, and G. Geoffrey Vining.  You are quoting a summary flowchart at the end of a chapter.  To understand what it's saying, please refer back to the relevant sections.  In this case it's section 10.2.1, *All Possible Regressions,* which contains extensive discussion of *computational* feasibility, concluding with a subsection entitled *Efficient Generation of All Possible Regressions* (p. 342).

Answer (score 1):

The feasibility in this context was indeed referring to the computing ability of a computer. According to D. Montgomery (and others), The feasibility of performing all possible is for about 30 or less explanatory variables.